# Unckecking and disabling a checkbox from a Radiobutton selection

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0

So I have a `radio group` with two `radio buttons` and also have one one `checkbox`
I want my `checkbox` become `enabled` when **tadiobutton2** gets selected and become `disabled` when **radioButton1** is selected.

To do that I gave a `x:Name` like blah to my `radioButton2` and then set `IsEnabled` of my `checkbox` like this:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName = blah, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

**Now** imagine they click on `radiobutton2`, and mark the `checkbox` as `Checked` and then click on **radioButton1**. 
What I also want to do is **to un-check the checkbox as well** when they go back and select **radiobutton1**

How can I do that?

NOTE: `IsChecked` of that `CheckBox` already some binding code to complicated stuff!(pulling from EF I guess) in it from the existing code so I don't want to break that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a good job for a `DataTrigger` like;

```
namespaces;
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"


    <StackPanel>
       <RadioButton x:Name="Radio1" RadioGroupName="blah" Content="I can make that thingy Disabled"/>
       <RadioButton x:Name="Radio2" RadioGroupName="blah" Content="I can make that thingy Enabled"/>

       <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Blahblahblah}">
         <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <ei:DataTrigger Value="False"
                            Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Radio1}">
                <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="IsEnabled"
                                         Value="False" />
            </ei:DataTrigger>
            <ei:DataTrigger Value="True"
                            Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Radio2}">
                <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="IsEnabled"
                                         Value="True" />
            </ei:DataTrigger>
         </i:Interaction.Triggers>
       </CheckBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

However just keep in mind amigo, you're getting to that point of questions asked where folks are generally going to start referring you to [this article](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). Questions here are generally less "How do I" and instead more of the "Why does this" type, if you get my meaning, either way hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Didn't know about this one, I ended up writing a "command" for it and handling it with a one liner in the command.

Comment: Ya, doing that sort of thing will draw some criticism from the MVVM purists out there. However the important thing is you found a solution. Cheers